# Merging Three hashes and getting this resultant hash

Tags: ruby

I have read the xls and have formed these three hashes

```
hash1=[{'name'=>'Firstname',
        'Locator'=>'id=xxx',
        'Action'=>'TypeAndWait'},
       {'name'=>'Password',
        'Locator'=>'id=yyy',
        'Action'=>'TypeAndTab'}]
```

Second Hash

```
hash2=[{'Test Name'=>'Example',
        'TestNumber'=>'Test1'},
       {'Test Name'=>'Example',
        'TestNumber'=>'Test2'}]
```

My Thrid Hash

```
hash3=[{'name'=>'Firstname',
        'Test1'=>'four',
        'Test2'=>'Five',
        'Test3'=>'Six'},
       {'name'=>'Password',
        'Test1'=>'Vicky',
        'Test2'=>'Sujin',
        'Test3'=>'Sivaram'}]
```

Now my resultant hash is

```
result={"Example"=>
         {"Test1"=>
           {'Firstname'=>
             ["id=xxx","four", "TypeAndWait"],
            'Password'=>
             ["id=yyy","Vicky", "TypeAndTab"]},
          "Test2"=>
           {'Firstname'=>
             ["id=xxx","Five", "TypeAndWait"],
            'Password'=>
             ["id=yyy","Sujin", "TypeAndTab"]}}}
```

I have gotten this result, but I had to write 60 lines of code in my program, but I don't think I have to write such a long program when I use Ruby, I strongly believe some easy way to achieve this. Can some one help me?

The second hash determines the which testcase has to be read, for an example, test3 is not present in the second testcase so resultant hash doesn't have test3.

Comment: I doubt I understand how the second hash affects result.

Comment: Okay give me sometime I will detail that.

Comment: @mudasobwa I have updated the question, sorry I made a mistake, second hash actually determines the testcase, test3 is not present in hash2 so resultant hash doesn't have test3

Comment: Asking to improve working code is off-topic on [so]. Also, even if it were on-topic, it would hard to improve the code when you don't show us the code. You may try asking on [codereview.se], but please make sure that read and understand their on-topic and off-topic pages, help center, FAQ, and metasite, just like you would on any other site before posting a question.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag I am not asking code improvement, I have done the coding but I feel it's length is more than 50 lines but mudasowa has written the same program in few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given three arrays, which I've renamed `arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3`. (`hash1`, `hash2` and `hash3` are not especially good names for arrays. :-))

```
arr1 = [{'name'=>'Firstname', 'Locator'=>'id=xxx', 'Action'=>'TypeAndWait'},
        {'name'=>'Password', 'Locator'=>'id=yyy', 'Action'=>'TypeAndTab'}]

arr2 = [{'Test Name'=>'Example', 'TestNumber'=>'Test1'},
        {'Test Name'=>'Example', 'TestNumber'=>'Test2'}]

arr3=[{'name'=>'Firstname', 'Test1'=>'four', 'Test2'=>'Five', 'Test3'=>'Six'},
      {'name'=>'Password', 'Test1'=>'Vicky', 'Test2'=>'Sujin', 'Test3'=>'Sivaram'}]
```

The drivers are the values `"Test1"` and `"Test2"` in the hashes that are elements of `arr2`. Nothing else in that array is needed, so let's extract those values (of which there could be any number, but here there are just two).

```
a2 = arr2.map { |h| h['TestNumber'] }
  #=> ["Test1", "Test2"]
```

Next we need to rearrange the information in `arr3` by creating a hash whose keys are the elements of `a2`.

```
h3 = a2.each_with_object({}) { |test,h|
  h[test] = arr3.each_with_object({}) { |f,g| g[f['name']] = f[test] } }
  #=> {"Test1"=>{"Firstname"=>"four", "Password"=>"Vicky"},
  #    "Test2"=>{"Firstname"=>"Five", "Password"=>"Sujin"}}
```

Next we need to rearrange the content of `arr1` by creating a hash whose keys match the keys of values of `h3`.

```
h1 = arr1.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g['name']] = g.reject { |k,_| k == 'name' } }
  #=> {"Firstname"=>{"Locator"=>"id=xxx", "Action"=>"TypeAndWait"}, 
  #    "Password"=>{"Locator"=>"id=yyy", "Action"=>"TypeAndTab"}}
```

It is now a simple matter of extracting information from these three objects.

```
{ 'Example'=>
  a2.each_with_object({}) do |test,h|
    h[test] = h3[test].each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),g|
      f = h1[k]
      g[k] = [f['Locator'], v, f['Action']]
    end
  end
}
  #=> {"Example"=>
  #     {"Test1"=>{"Firstname"=>["id=xxx", "four", "TypeAndWait"],
  #                "Password"=>["id=yyy", "Vicky", "TypeAndTab"]},
  #      "Test2"=>{"Firstname"=>["id=xxx", "Five", "TypeAndWait"],
  #                "Password"=>["id=yyy", "Sujin", "TypeAndTab"]}}}
```

Comment: Accepted your answer! This is the most perfect answer! Thanks for spending your time and thanks for taking time to explain me.

Comment: Hi, I think you have taken my old data and have written the code accordingly, that was wrong and I have changed the data(please look at the question once again for new arrays), I don't know how you have gotten my old data. I have taken data from your answer part so it worked fine. But when I tried to execute my new arrays, it throwing this error. `C:/Users/rajagopalan.m/RubymineProjects/SingaporeLife/Source/Utils/ReadXls.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: (continued...) Firstname and Firstname-id is not related so I changed that as `'name'=>'Firstname',
        'Locator'=>'id=xxx` .

Comment: I updated my answer to be consistent with your current data.

Comment: you are so helpful

Answer (score 1):

What do you call `hash{1-2-3}` are arrays in the first place. Also, I am pretty sure you have mistyped `hash1#Locator` and/or `hash3#name`. The code below works for this exact data, but it should not be hard to update it to reflect any changes.

```
hash2.
  map(&:values).
  group_by(&:shift).
  map do |k, v|
    [k, v.flatten.map do |k, v|
          [k, hash3.map do |h3|
                # lookup a hash from hash1
                h1 = hash1.find do |h1|
                   h3['name'].start_with?(h1['Locator'])
                end
                # can it be nil btw?
                [
                  h1['name'],
                  [
                    h3['name'][/.*(?=-id)/],
                    h3[k],
                    h1['Action']
                  ]
                ]
          end.to_h]
    end.to_h]
  end.to_h
```

Comment: First of all, this is awesome! Exactly what I have expected, actually I am reading the data from three xls sheet and formulating this data-structure for further use. and I have included `-id` just to distinguish from name,-id is not important. But thanks for writing regular expression for that as well. Unfortunately I have only one upvote, otherwise I would have given more upvote for this coding.Do you know I have waited for your arrival to post this question, I saw you are started commenting in some other question, so I posted :(  Thank you once again. You reduced my bigger work.

Comment: From here it is easy. Remove start_with and remove regexp.

Comment: I tried but it's giving me the wrong result. It is not bringing the locator inside,it is bringing me the `password` in the place of locator. Can you please look at the question once again, I have neatly updated now. It's giving me this result `{"Example"=>{"Test1"=>{"Firstname"=>["Password", "Vicky", "TypeAndWait"]}, "Test2"=>{"Firstname"=>["Password", "Sujin", "TypeAndWait"]}}}`  You see, it's not including the locator part now.

Comment: Hi, changed my first hash `hash1=[{'Firstname'=>['id=xxx','TypeAndWait'],'Password'=>['id=yyy','TypeAndTab']}]` and then changed your program a bit  `[
          h3['name'],
          [
              h1[h3['name']],
              h3[k]
          ].flatten
      ]`  By this change I have achieved the result. Thanks for helping me